# Openbox placing cursor on the window titlebar

Tags: openbox

I was able to use one really neat thing. In many DE or WM, when you **Maximize** the window and then try drag the window from the **Titlebar**, the window would be **Unmaximized**. I achieved this by the following config:

```
<context name="Titlebar">
 <mousebind button="Left" action="Drag">
  <action name="Unmaximize"/>
  <action name="Move"/>
 </mousebind>
</context>
```

The **Move** action is necessary to keep to be still moving window.

BUT there is one thing...I hope you can help me..

This way, when window becomes, **Unmaximized**. The cursor will still be on top of the screen. How to move the cursor to still be on a **Titlebar**?